# Opening OAuth2 Authorization URL in a browser control

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to learn about the Google's Drive API while I am writing a little program. I am using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker class for asking the user to give the app permissions, but the drawback is that it is automatically opening a new browser tab in Chrome (as an example):

```
const string ApplicationName = "TestApp";
string[] scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };

UserCredential credential;

using (var stream =
    new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart");
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get the AuthorizationURL so I can show a browser dialog with it, and therefore get the respective token.

How can that be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the way the client library is written it will automatically open it in the default browser.

There is an issue request already for this feature. [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker in embedded browser? #547](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/547)

**Answer**: There is currently no way to get the Authorization url so that you can sow the dialog on your own.  The client library is an open source project so you can add it.